# Create or Open file and then Append data to it

Tags: c#, .net, streamwriter

We can use such code to open or create file and then write some data into it (all contents will be replaced).

```
using (var file = File.Open(path, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
    using (var stream = new StreamWriter(file))
        stream.WriteLine(_message);
```

Or we can use following code to add data at the end of the file, assuming that the file is exist.

```
using (var file = File.Open(path, FileMode.Append))
    using (var stream = new StreamWriter(file))
        stream.WriteLine(_message);
```

Is there any way to combine these 3 things: ((Create || Open) & Append) to the file?

Comment: Where would you expect the file pointer to be? The difference between OpenOrCreate and Append (on an existing file) is where the file pointer is.

Comment: First make shure that file is exist, (if not, create it) and then append.
I understand how to do this in 10-12 code lines, but is there any elegant solution?

Comment: `but is there any elegant solution` <= You can create your own `FileStream` factory. Also its not even that much code, maybe 1 line more. `using (var file = File.Exists(path) ? File.Open(path, FileMode.Append) : File.Open(path, FileMode.Create))`

Comment: Call `File.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.End)`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create your own `FileStream` factory or you could do it on one line like so.

```
using (var file = File.Exists(path) ? File.Open(path, FileMode.Append) : File.Open(path, FileMode.CreateNew))
using (var stream = new StreamWriter(file))
    stream.WriteLine(_message);
```

Comment: leave the `file.exists` away, you should catch the exception if one occurs 
the problem is that the file state could change between `file.exists` and `file.open`, an exception would be thrown there anyway

Answer (score 10):

If you want to append data to a file, just call `File.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.End)`. This sets the file pointer to the end of the file, which is where it would be after opening a file with `FileMode.Append`.

For example:

```
using (var file = File.Open(path, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
{
    file.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.End);
    using (var stream = new StreamWriter(file))
        stream.WriteLine(_message);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

From Documentation of `FileMode.Append`:

> Opens the file if it exists and seeks to the end of the file, or
>   creates a new file. This requires Append permission. FileMode.Append
>   can be used only in conjunction with FileAccess.Write. Trying to seek
>   to a position before the end of the file throws an IOException
>   exception, and any attempt to read fails and throws a
>   NotSupportedException exception.

[Source learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.io.filemode?view=netframework-4.8)

So Append does exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but it may help someone

You can open, by ORing the types

```
using (var file = File.Open(path, FileMode.OpenOrCreate | FileMode.Append))
```

Comment: Because the `FileMode` enum is not a `Flags` enum, this is not a valid approach.  The example you gave does compile and run because 4 | 6 = 6.  Therefore, the code is identical to `using (var file = File.Open(path, FileMode.Append))`.  However, this will not work for most `FileMode` combinations (e.g. `FileMode.Open | FileMode.Append` would be invalid).